# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity}

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin

I have android SDK app in which I have many flutter modules. when I am launching the module I am getting a crash saying "Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The requested cached FlutterEngine did not exist in the FlutterEngineCache: 'my_engine_id'
". This is an Intermediate crash, which is being logged on firebase for almost 0.1% user.

To launch the flutter module from SDK below are the steps

1. FlutterIntentProvider.kt

```
if (activity == null) {
    instance!!.flutterEngine =
        FlutterEngine(MyApplication.getInstance().currentActivity.applicationContext)
} else {
    instance!!.flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(activity)
}
instance!!.flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
    DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
)

try {
    FlutterEngineCache
        .getInstance().clear()

    FlutterEngineCache
        .getInstance()
        .put(ENGINE_ID, instance!!.flutterEngine)

    GeneratedPluginRegister.registerGeneratedPlugins(instance!!.flutterEngine)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // logging exception
}


if (baseActivity == null ||
    !FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().contains(ENGINE_ID)
) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(Throwable("Engine Id not found"))
    return false
}

when (moduleName) {
    Constant.MODULE1 -> Module1PlatformChannels(flutterEngine, baseActivity!!).init()

    Constant.MODULE2 -> Module2PlatformChannels(flutterEngine, baseActivity!!).init()
}

return FlutterActivity.withCachedEngine(ENGINE_ID)
    .build(context)
```

Module1PlatformChannels.kt

```
class Module1PlatformChannels(engine: FlutterEngine, activity: BaseActivity) {
    private val flutterEngine: FlutterEngine = engine
    val baseActivity: BaseActivity = activity

    fun init() {
        initEpfChannel()
    }

    private fun initEpfChannel() {
        MethodChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            "MODULE1"
        ).setMethodCallHandler { call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result ->
            if (call.method == "buildType") {
                result.success(buildType)
            }
    }
}
```

Now inside view

```
activity.startActivity(
    FlutterInterface.getInstance()
        .startFlutterIntent(activity, "", "", Constant.MODULE1)
)
```

Note: when i am not clearing the engine cache it is taking me back to the 1st module which I have launched for the 1st time again-2 irrespective of what I want to launch. That's why I am clearing it 1st and then creating the new one. Also when I am not using the cache engine then screen is getting blank for some time.